# Spring - unable to map the servlet. It returns 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am trying to make a simple servlet, but I am getting the error status of 404 Not Found.

This is my `servlet` code

```java
package servlets;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


@WebServlet(name = "ServletExample", urlPatterns = "/theServlet")
public class ServletExample extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        message = "Hello from the servlet";
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //set response type
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        //actual logic goes here.
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //do nothing
    }

}
```

and this is my `web.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.ServletExample</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Example</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The url's I tried:

`http://localhost:8080/Project/Example`

`http://localhost:8080/Example`

`http://localhost:8080/theServlet`

`http://localhost:8080/Project/theServlet`

Comment: and have you tried `http://localhost:8080/theServlet` which is mentioned in the annotation? And how do you deploy your project?

Comment: Yes, I also tried `http://localhost:8080/theServlet` but it does not work. I am using `Tomcat 8.5.39` for this project.

Comment: Provide more information:  no one is a clairvoyant at SO.

Comment: What kind of information do I need to provide? I am new to servlets and I thought this information is enough!

Comment: I think you need to use :
http://localhost:8080/Example/theServlet
'Example' should show as a deployed application on Tomcat management gui

Comment: @jr593 It is not working. The only thing that is working here is the `localhost:8080/Project` which renders a simple `index.html` file that I created on my project.

Comment: It is confusing that you are configuring your servlet both with annotations and "traditional" web.xml - you should decide for one of them!

Comment: @GyroGearless I just tried with only xml and also only annotations, but I am still getting the 404 Not Found. I tried those url's with annotations: `http://localhost:8080/Project/theServlet`
`http://localhost:8080/theServlet`
With xml I tried:
`http://localhost:8080/Project/Example`
`http://localhost:8080/Example`

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the lines in the web.xml about sevlet mapping .. and .. balises because you are already defining this configurations in the class, and you can call the servlet by http://localhost:8080/Project/theServlet.

Comment: You are using Apache tomcat?

Comment: Could you please give us the content of context.xml

Comment: Yes, I am using Apache tomcat. What do you mean by `content of context.xml` ? I provided the `web.xml`.

Comment: If you are using Tomcat so there is a configuration file for the project called context.xml

Comment: And how can I access that file?

Comment: I just found that my project does not have the file named context.xml, so I generated one and here it is the content on it `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/">
</Context>` . What should I add in order the servlets to work ?

Comment: try to change the path to path="/Project"

Comment: and try to use the path that I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using both annotations and web.xml. A “best practice” is to try to use one or the other. You can entirely drop web.xml file if you choose to rely on annotations for all of your Servlet configurations. But I still encourage you to keep that file, or at least have one like shown in the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Servlet with Annotations Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

And try calling http://localhost:8080/Project/theServlet

Comment: I did exactly what you said. Unfortunately, I am getting the same 404 Status.